# Unable to access Rabbit MQ Management page using IP Address

Tags: rabbitmq

I enabled Rabbitmq Management plugin. It works fine if I try to access as http://localhost:15672.
However from remote system if I tried to access using the IP address (where rabbitMQ is installed), then it shows page can not be displayed.
Example: http://192.168.1.191:15672 when tried to access, below error message it displays:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Able to fix this issue, it was firewall which blocked.